# ESRI Image Service On Google Earth API

Tags: kml, google-earth, image-service, google-earth-enterprise, arcgis-image-server

I've been started developing GoogleEarth API on web. I'm using GoogleEarth plugin 7.1.2 version. It is probably a simple question but I'm having trouble with that.

I'm trying to integrate the [ArcGIS Image Extension for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/image-extension) (version 10.1) to a web application based on google plugin and server enterprise, or at least find a proper solution. I know that there is a way to publish ESRI service as KML but I want it to be a last resort cause the image service is outsource

Sorry if my English is not that good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what you need. 
[Rest API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000w0000000) bring up a wrapper for Image Service that provide KMZ file output.

Syntax example: 
http://"imageservice-url"/kml/image.kmz

Answer (score 1):

Allen is right, but to add to his suggestion, you should be able to use GE API ***fetchKml()*** method with the correct ArcGIS Server kml endpoint to integrate the service. Just make sure that the KML capability has been enabled on the service you are trying to connect to.

The KML endpoint on arcgis server should look like:

```
http://<host>/arcgis/rest/services/<folder>/<service_name>/MapServer/generateKml?docName=&l%3A0=on&layers=0&layerOptions=composite
```

Notice there are some additional query options on the url for managing which layers are included.  For more info, check out:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004pt000000